# Dynamically use HashMap to populate columns in listView

Tags: java, android, string, listview

I am using `HashMap` to put the data in `TextView` inside a `ListView` but I am unable to dynamically populate the list I am able to get only the first row as output. or How to do each for the hash string.

**code -**

```
for (int i=0; i<result.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject notice = result.getJSONObject(0);
    id[i] = notice.getString(KEY_ID);
    name[i] = notice.getString(KEY_NAME);
    date_from[i] = notice.getString(KEY_DATE_FROM);
    date_to[i] = notice.getString(KEY_DATE_TO);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    HashMap<String, String> temp= new HashMap<String, String>();
    temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, id[i]);
    temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, name[i]);
    temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, date_from[i]);
    temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, date_to[i]);
    list.add(temp);
    ListViewAdapters adapter = new ListViewAdapters(this, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**Custom ListViewAdapter -**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.colmn_row, null);

        txtFirst=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtSecond=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        txtThird=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.age);
        txtFourth=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

    }


    HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
    txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
    txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
    txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
    txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you have shared, you are putting everything inside loop which is recreating `ArrayList` and `ListView` again and again. As a result, your list and listview contain only last item (one row). Do this -

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
for (int i=0; i<result.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject notice = result.getJSONObject(i);
    id[i] = notice.getString(KEY_ID);
    name[i] = notice.getString(KEY_NAME);
    date_from[i] = notice.getString(KEY_DATE_FROM);
    date_to[i] = notice.getString(KEY_DATE_TO);

    HashMap<String, String> temp= new HashMap<String, String>();
    temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, id[i]);
    temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, name[i]);
    temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, date_from[i]);
    temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, date_to[i]);
    list.add(temp);
}
    ListViewAdapters adapter = new ListViewAdapters(this, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The code does loop and show the rows but all the row values are same. Please help

Comment: @AsfanUlla Are you getting this after trying using my code? Are you now able to see all rows (maybe with same value).

Comment: If yes, then I think your problem is in this line - JSONObject notice = result.getJSONObject(0); Please provide more code. i.e. where your result is coming from.

Comment: Thank you solved it just needed to change  result.getJSONObject(0); to result.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: Yes, that's what i felt :-)